# When did the Astra Space test flight 006 actually reach max-Q? There is substantial disagreement in the audio feed of the launch (Launch Vehicle 0006)

Tags: launch, max-q, astra-space

Watching the NASA Spaceflight video *Astra Test Flight (Launch Vehicle 0006)* linked below it seems the launch was terminated, but at least on the video there was no audible [Earth-shattering kaboom](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+kaboom).

**Question:** When did the Astra Space test flight 006 actually reach max-Q? There is some disagreement in the audio feed of the launch. It's mentioned at `T+ 00:02:02` and again 32 seconds later at `T+ 00:02:34`.

Altitudes and speeds are indicated in an inset at the lower right-hand corner of the video.

- https://astra.com/
- https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=44689.0

my attempt at transcription:

```
T+ 00:00:00  1:33:38
T+ 00:00:52  1:34:30 (rocket now inaudible over the noisy ground LOX tank venting)
T+ 00:01:36  1:35:14 rocket has cleared the island 
T+ 00:01:56  1:35:34 approaching nominal downrange trajectory, tracking (330 m/s 13 km), 
T+ 00:02:02  1:35:40 and at this point we should have also passed max-Q
T+ 00:02:31  1:36:09 engine shuts off, rocket immediately starts rapidly rotating/tumbling
T+ 00:02:34  1:36:12 vehicle has passed through max-Q
T+ 00:02:38  1:36:16 terminate sent(?)
T+ 00:02:44  1:36:22 terminate received
```

cued at final countdown:

Comment: companion question: [Roughly how high does a rocket have to get before the self-destruct becomes inaudible? Invisible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54794/12102)

Comment: Educated guess, so won't answer, but the rocket lost one of five engines at launch, so it would have been accelerating significantly more slowly than planned. I suspect "we should have passed max Q" call was when the nominal flight plan would have maxed Q, and the later call was when it actually did. The announcer would have a cheat sheet with max Q marked at around 2:00. At that time, she didn't hear anyone call max Q, and said "we should have passed max Q [according to my cheat sheet/if this were a nominal flight]". The other voice is reporting closer to the actual time of max Q.

Comment: @RussellBorogove the altitude and speed readouts may be helpful here, if they come from telemetry/tracking rather than being scripted as well. The density varies as roughly exp( -h / 8 km) so I wonder if one can be quickly ruled out?

Comment: I note the velocity readout shortly after launch, when the booster was really struggling, went from -1m/s to -7m/s before they turned it off, so the telemetry readout was both *not scripted* and *not correct*. (I assume this was some edge case where the unexpected horizontal travel screwed up the vertical velocity measurement somehow). Display came back at T+1:49 or so.

Comment: I'd guess actual max q was when it hit the water. ;-)

Comment: @TomSpilker indeed; that factor of 1000 in density probably takes the cake.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic pressure is straightforward to calculate:
$$q = \tfrac12\, \rho\, v^{2}$$

Where $\rho$ is the density of the air and $v$ is velocity.

Using the available onscreen velocity and altitude figures, and assuming an atmospheric [scale height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height) of 8.5km and sea level density of 1.225 kg/m^3, I get a max Q of about 17 KPa at T+2:11, at 530 m/s and 19 km.

However, this is a poor estimate for at least three reasons:

- The altitude figures are severely rounded off, to the point where my spreadsheet shows multiple local maxima rather than the expected smooth quadratic with a single maximum;
- My quick and dirty spreadsheet model assumes a strict exponential air density falloff, not taking air temperature into account;
- The onscreen velocity figures in the early part of the launch, when the rocket is struggling with a failed engine, are negative, and it's unclear if whatever caused that measurement/display error was dealt with during the minute and a half or so that the display was turned off.

Thus, I can't say whether the actual max Q was closer to the 2:02 call or the 2:34 call.

The most likely scenario is that:

- The 2:02 call was given on the announcer's flight timeline cheat sheet, and not having heard confirmation, the female announcer said "we *should have* passed max Q" -- meaning, in a nominal flight, they would have. This was not a nominal flight; one of the five engines failed immediately at liftoff, bringing the rocket's TWR perilously close to 1, and it lost several seconds barely hovering, when a nominal flight would have been accelerating and making progress towards max Q.
- Max Q occurred after nominal time, possibly around 2:11, possibly later still, and the male speaker simply didn't mention it immediately for some reason, and then at 2:34 said "vehicle *has passed through* max Q", meaning that it happened some time in the past.

A more detailed atmospheric altitude/density model would help settle the uncertainty, but I'm not getting paid enough to dig one up.

Comment: checking back [in the beginning](https://youtu.be/O8Tdm797BzM?t=119) and [the end](https://youtu.be/O8Tdm797BzM?t=5917) I think it's safe to say that the announcer is Carolina Grossman, who's name card says "Director of Product Management". Hopefully my latest startup SERepBitDoge (SE reputation to Bit-and Doge-coin conversion technology) will be up and running soon and we can *quadruple your pay* for a "modest fee" soon! It uses blockchain cubesats, but don't tell anybody yet.